# How can I hide sensitive photos

Tags: macos, finder, photos, privacy

My problem is I've got heaps of photos that I don't want to be found in finder is their any easy way to stop finder from showing them in places like All Files or quicklook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I exclude the display of specific pictures and videos in the Finder?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23479/how-can-i-exclude-the-display-of-specific-pictures-and-videos-in-the-finder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1. Exclude such folders in the Spotlight search. Any one else using the Mac can easily find and go through the content.
2. Create a new Disk Image (preferably encrypt it) in **Disk Utility** and it is a separate disk which grows and shrinks based on the contents. You could also use apps like [Knox](https://agilebits.com/knox) to achieve the same.
3. Try apps like [Skedaddle](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/skedaddle/id444419698?mt=12) to hide from Finder. Skedaddle protects the files with a password and Spotlight cannot find it. It does not encrypt the data.

Comment: Option 2 is the best choice in that the data is truly removed from spotlight databases as well as encrypted in case someone accesses your hard drive (and bypasses the password you have set on your account or your firmware). The other suggestions are nice for light protection, but are more fragile and if the files are truly sensitive, option 2 would be my choice here.

Comment: Both the answers were really helpful cheers

Comment: Make sure it's a **sparse** image! Otherwise I believe it won't grow or shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden folder and put your private files (not only pictures) there.
They won't show up in spotlight or a finder search (basically both are the same)
To make a hidden folder, open the terminal app and type:
`mkdir /.private`

This will create a folder named `.private` in the root of your Hard drive.
Then you can only access this in finder by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and entering `/.private`.

Of course you can name the folder anything you want and put it anywhere, but it has to start with a dot to be hidden, and you have to remember where you put it.

Comment: Why put it in the root? That seems like...not a good idea. `~/.private` would be better. (:

Comment: I guess I chose the shortest and simplest path for the sake of the example, but exactly why the me of 2012 chose it, I think we'll never know.