# Crawl computer for node_modules, add .nosync file

Tags: macos, icloud

Per https://medium.com/@isaiah.taylor/how-to-maintain-node-projects-with-icloud-drive-4c6549f7c806, I can prevent node_modules folders from syncing via iCloud Drive.

Trouble is: there's often a lot of node_modules folders. A lot, a lot. And I often forget before I start copying.

Questions
(1) Is there a way to crawl through my hard drive, find node_modules folders and add a .nosync file?

(2) Is there a way to keep this crawling going in the background? So that this crawling would happen for any new folders? Wonder if this is a Hammerspoon kind of thing maybe?

Comment: Wouldn‘t it be easier to just but the files outside of the directory hierarchy synced by iCloud?

Comment: I use two computers and frequently want to share a project to go work upstairs on my laptop for a while. I'll throw the folder onto the desktop and let it sync. I always, always forget to delete node_modules first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run the following to create a `.nosync` file in each `node_modules` folder

```
find ~ -type d -name node_modules -exec touch {}/.nosync \;
```

This will look through everything in your home directory. You can limit it to the `Desktop` folder by replacing `~` with `~/Desktop`.

To have the command run regularly you can create a crontab entry:

- Run `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` to start editing. If you haven't created another entry before the file will be empty
- Add

  ```
  0 * * * * find $HOME -type d -name node_modules -exec touch {}/.nosync \;
  ```

  to have it run every full hour, or

  ```
  0 */3 * * * find $HOME -type d -name node_modules -exec touch {}/.nosync \;
  ```

  to run it every three hours
- Type <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> and answer "Y" on the save prompt

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to do this ....regularly? Like have it run once a day or something?

Comment: @saltcod see updated answer

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you so much!  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: This doesn’t work as of 2021, you need .nosync in the folder name. See other answer

Answer (score 2):

It turns out putting a file called `.nosync` in the folders you wish to icloud ignore no longer works (as in the accepted answer), so changing the folder name to end with .nosync, and adding a symlink, is the next best option.

Here is a shell function (put it in .zshrc or .bashrc) called "nosync" which recurses through Documents and Desktop, adding the `.nosync` to the end of your .git folders and node_modules folders, and creating a symlink to the new hidden folder from the original location. This script correctly handles nested folders (only symlinks and ignores top level node_modules). This script also adds the attribute which tells Dropbox to ignore a file (for those of you also using Dropbox sync). In order to run it you new to `brew install findutils`, because standard mac find command doesn't support the fancy stuff.

```
nosync() {
  # GNU find (brew install findutils), because it supports xtype, find directories, following symlinks, where the end file (not following its symlink (via -xtype)) is not a symlink
  # and the path is not under a nosync dir, and the path is pruned (no nested node_modules)
  # move the folder to a dot file which is dropbox and icloud ignored, symlink the old folder, and suppress cyclical symlink warnings

  gfind -L ~/Documents -name node_modules -prune -not -path '*.nosync*' -type d -not -xtype l -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(dirname "$0")/.$(basename "$0").nosync" && ln -s "$(dirname "$0")/.$(basename "$0").nosync" "$0" && xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1 "$(dirname "$0")/.$(basename "$0").nosync" && echo "$0"' {} \; 2> >(grep -v "File system loop detected")
  gfind -L ~/Desktop -name node_modules -prune -not -path '*.nosync*' -type d -not -xtype l -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$(dirname "$0")/.$(basename "$0").nosync" && ln -s "$(dirname "$0")/.$(basename "$0").nosync" "$0" && xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1 "$(dirname "$0")/.$(basename "$0").nosync" && echo "$0"' {} \; 2> >(grep -v "File system loop detected")

  # adds a dot for node_modules, but not for .git, which is already hidden

  gfind -L ~/Documents -name .git -prune -not -path '*.nosync*' -type d -not -xtype l -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$0".nosync && ln -s "$0".nosync "$0" && xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1 "$0".nosync && echo "$0"' {} \;  2> >(grep -v "File system loop detected")
  gfind -L ~/Desktop -name .git -prune -not -path '*.nosync*' -type d -not -xtype l -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "$0".nosync && ln -s "$0".nosync "$0" && xattr -w com.dropbox.ignored 1 "$0".nosync && echo "$0"' {} \;  2> >(grep -v "File system loop detected")
}
```

You might want to set up a cron job to run this script every so often.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `yarn global add nosync-icloud` and then `ns` in every directory you want to unsunc node_modules in. Kudos to [this repo](https://github.com/haochuan9421/nosync-icloud).