# Why does Spotlight search no longer work after a system update?

Tags: spotlight, search, mds

After a recent system update (to Catalina) Spotlight stopped working. Additional symptoms:

- I could add volumes to the Spotlight>Privacy list and then remove them with the - button but it made no difference
- And volumes which I added to that list would disappear from the list after a restart
- Various Terminal attempts using mdutil, e.g., `sudo mdutil -E <VolumeName>` mostly returned "Indexing and searching disabled.", sometimes with a message tag `-> kMDConfigSearchLevelOff`

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that after a failed update (to Monterey, long sad story) earlier this year, most of my disks had a file (invisible because of the dot) named ".metadata_never_index_unless_rootfs" at the top of the directory hierarchy. The files all had creation dates from around the time of the Monterey fiasco. After noticing this file, making a wild guess and deleting it, and then restarting, the problems all went away.